# Как правильно составить Intent Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mime-type

У меня есть активити от приложения eMotions от Мегафон - вот манифест:

```
       <activity
        android:name="ru.megalabs.multifon.screens.main.activities.EmotionActivity"
        android:launchMode="2"
        android:screenOrientation="1"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12">
```

```
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:scheme="sip" />

            <data
                android:scheme="imto" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/ru.megalabs.multifon.tel" />

            <data
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/ru.megalabs.multifon.sms" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

Вопрос - как мне правильно составить Intent запрос, и передать данные mimeType, так что бы при нажатии кнопки из моего приложения, открывалось вот это приложение и отправляло смс? Открыть просто приложение eMotion из своего приложения это у меня выходит, а вот что бы смс отправляло - нет.

Comment: Action send + put extra?

Comment: @Романыч как именно это написать? я пытался intent.putExtra("sip", "89856484648"); и ничего, открывает просто приложение и все

Comment: Стоит погуглить в сторону android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT и других подобных штук.

Comment: @Романыч я не могу понять как куда это пихать. Можешь мне скинуть целиком код как мне сделать так что б отправилось смс

Comment: Типа того.  Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123"); Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri); it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text"); startActivity(it);

Comment: @Романыч да делал я так, не отправляет это приложение смс. А еще как приложение поймет что именно оно должно отправить смс, а не стандартное смс приложение?

Comment: Прочитайье про неявный интент. Система спросит какое приложение открыть. Или же просто вызвать по имени пакета приложения вот и все

Comment: @Романыч я в курсе, а мне надо что б оно автоматически взяло и отправило смс.  И еще даже при этом раскладе мое приложение не появляется в этом списке

Comment: Оно должно иметь permission на отправку смс. Т.к отправка смс имеет разряд dangerous его надо запрашивать в runtime.

Comment: И потом, после всего этого , вызывать по имени пакета прилажку и слать мессаге. Думаю схема примерно такова. Когда будет установлен нужный Permission, оно будет появлятся в списке. Когда будет получено разрешение на отправку в runtime - оно будет слать автоматически